# html code for playlist not working on blogger

Tags: html, blogger, playlist

I wrote this HTML code on the HTML gadget of blogger -

```
<embed name="2playlist"
    src="2playlist.m3u"
    width="300"
    height="90"
    loop="false"
    hidden="false"
    autostart="true">
</embed>
```

But it's not working. I have little knowledge of HTML, I found this code online. Any suggestions?

Thank you.

Comment: I just realized that there's an error in my m3u file. It is not playing when i click on it. But I'm unable to edit it or see the file in text version. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is in your `src="2playlist.m3u"`. You should set the source by hotlinking the `.m3u` file, for example: `http://example.com/music/2playlist.m3u` because blogger have no directory system like WordPress.

Comment: Okay, so how do I hotlink it? I have made another playlist since that one wasn't working.

Comment: you can upload your `2playlist.m3u` file to a free hosting that allow hotlinking such as dropbox.

but remember, `m3u` file is a playlist file that will call the `mp3` file. So, you will need to make sure that your mp3 file that called by the m3u file have the correct `path`.

Answer (score 0):

This code uses three kinds of files: *html*, *m3u*, and *mp3*. The code you posted loads a music playlist (m3u), which in turn loads audio files (mp3).

Make sure all these files are in the same directory (folder):

- your html file containing posted code
- 2playlist.m3u
- all the audio files listed in your m3u file

If you need help creating the m3u file, see step one at http://www.quackit.com/html/codes/create_music_playlist.cfm.

Edit: Since blogger doesn't support directories, you need to put the **absolute file path** rather than the **relative file path**. Basically, rather than putting `src="2playlist.m3u`, you need to have an m3u file somewhere on the internet, and you need to put it's url there instead of 2playlist.m3u.

Comment: Sorry, by not working I meant that on opening the website, the music doesn't play automatically. Even on clicking the play button, it does't work
I got it from http://www.quackit.com/html/codes/create_music_playlist.cfm